# bash update file list of filenames with full path

Tags: bash, awk, sed, find

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
 Jan 1 06:09:23 somefile.txt
 Jan 2 12:18:27 somefile1.txt
 Jan 3 04:16:00 somefile2.txt
```

I would like to find each file and insert the full path of each file into this file. I would think there is some combination of find, awk and sed that would accomplish this but so far I have not come up with a viable solution to update the file to look as below.

```
Jan 1 06:09:23 /path/to/file/somefile.txt
Jan 2 12:18:27 /path/to/file1/somefile1.txt
Jan 3 04:16:00 /path/to/file2/somefile2.txt
```

I have been able to strip out the file name and find the files without issue but what I have come up with so far writes out a new file and looses the original file contents. I had hoped to keep the original file in tact.

```
#!/bin/bash
#functions
getup(){

for i in `cat /home/work/uploadtmp`
do
     find /home/uploads/*$i 2> /dev/null >> /home/work/upfile
done
}

listfile(){
while read line; do ls -lt $line; done < /home/work/upfile

}

#run functions
getup
listfile | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4}' | sort -k1M -k2 -k3 > /home/log/newfile
```

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: ...and don't try to use `ls` programmatically: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: And don't use `>>` inside a loop -- it's *much* more efficient to put a `>outfile` on the *outside* of the loop, so you're opening the file only once, vs reopening it every time you want to append a line.

Comment: Is this a GNU system? Do you have `readlink -f` available?

Comment: Which file, exactly has the format in question? `uploadtmp`? Or are you expecting the output of your `ls -lt` to be of that format?

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing issues it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: Thank You Charles for the advice!

Comment: Yes I did try readlink -f but I did not get it to.work. The system is Linux with a bash shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# create a temporary output file, so we only overwrite the destination when complete
tempfile=$(mktemp /home/log/newfile.XXXXXX)

# ...and tell the shell to delete that temporary file if it's still around when we exit
# ...won't work for SIGKILL or power failures, but better than nothing.
trap 'rm -f -- "$tempfile"' EXIT

# iterate over lines in the input file...
while read -r mon day time filename; do
  # ...quoting each name to only match itself...
  filename_pat=$(sed -e 's@[]*?[]@\\&@g'  <<<"$filename")
  # ...using find to locate the first file with the given name for each...
  fullname=$(find /home/uploads -name "$filename_pat" -print -quit)
  # ...and printing that new name on our stdout
  printf '%s\n' "$mon $day $time $fullname"
done </home/work/uploadtmp >"$tempfile" # ...redirecting the whole loop to our tempfile...

# ...then performing a single atomic rename to overwrite the final destination
mv "$tempfile" /home/log/newfile
```

Comment: This script worked perfectly once I removed the -quit from the fullname variable. Not sure why that prevented the variable from being populated

Comment: @bdamon, ooh -- needed a `-print` before the `-quit`. If you don't have the `-quit`, by the way, then you'll have bugs when there are two files with the same name, since both names will end up stored in the variable with a newline between them.

Comment: Thanks again @Charles Duffy! There will be times when there are files with the same name. btw the spellcheck site is excellent, something I really needed!

Comment: to be fair, btw, we'll still have bugs in that case, just *different* bugs -- looking for `foo.txt`, we're currently find the *first* one, not the *newest* one or the one with a specific upload time. Your best bet is to have whatever software generates `uploadtmp` actually generate qualified pathnames, rather than trying to reconstruct them after-the-fact.

Comment: (also, critiquing security bugs in the answer by @JamesBrown reminded me to look carefully at my own, hence the change to escape names before passing them to `find` -- that way a file named `*.txt` [with a literal `*` in its name] results in `find` looking for a file with exactly that name, not any file with a `.txt` extension).

Answer (score 0):

In awk, using `find` externally to collect file paths:

```
$ cat program.awk
NR==FNR {                 # read in the files file records
    a[$NF]=$0; next }         # hash them to a and tskip o the next record
{                         # find produced list processing
    n=split($0,b,"/");        # basename functionality, filename part in b[n]
    if(sub(b[n],$0,a[b[n]]))  # replace filename in a with full path version
        print a[b[n]]         # and print
}
$ awk -f program.awk files <(find .)
Jan 3 04:16:00 ./file2/somefile2.txt
Jan 1 06:09:23 ./file/somefile.txt
Jan 2 12:18:27 ./file1/somefile1.txt
```

This solution (or the old) doesn't tolerate space in the filenames. It is easily solvable in the first block, though, by ditching the `$NF` usage:

```
f=$0                      # current record to var f
sub(/^([^ ]+ ){3}/,"",f)  # remove timestamp
a[f]=$0                   # hash to a on f
next                      # ...
```

**The old version** that @CharlesDuffy critizices in the comments (++ for it). Left here for educational purposes:

```
$ awk -v path=".." '{ s="find " path " -name " $NF; s | getline $NF } 1' file
Jan 1 06:09:23 ../test/file/somefile.txt
Jan 2 12:18:27 ../test/file1/somefile1.txt
Jan 3 04:16:00 ../test/file2/somefile2.txt
```

- `find` command string is gathered to var `s`
- which is executed and output is written back to last field (`$NF`)

Comment: Consider what happens if you have a filename uploaded that contains `$(rm -rf $HOME)` in it. Substituting data into generated code is almost the very definition of how one gets injection vulnerabilities (be they shell injection -- as here -- or SQL injection), and that's exactly what this is doing here.

Comment: ...well, to be fair -- since we're taking only the last field, `$(rm -rf $HOME)` would only parse as `$HOME)`, but then, that's another bug on its own. One-word commands (without arguments) are trivially executable this way (`$(/home/uploads/run-my-script)`), or semicolon-separated series; figuring out exactly one can do with that's an interesting exercise for an attacker, but in any event, it's a dangerous property to have for something that's going to be handling uploaded files with unknown names.

Comment: I had to think a little bit about how to pull off arbitrary command execution, but a file named `../test/file/$(IFS=@;payload=rm@-rf@$HOME;$payload).txt` will do the trick -- no spaces, so it'll work even with `$NF` trimming everything but the last space-separated path segment.